# React, Json Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

So basically I have a Json file which has arrays, I have 2 components Champions and Skills where array is displayed, it is maping through items when I click on the div it display that specific. Now I have created Search Component and I want from it when I write the name of the object which is in the json file, that it only displays that one and hides the others, I have started it building it, I would like to know if I am on the right track and if I am not I would be very grateful if I got some help. Note:I got more items in Json file

```
Champion component
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import data from './data.json'
import  './Champions.css'
import Skills from './Skills'



const Champions = () => {
  const [toggleShow, setToggleShow] = useState(false);
  const [currentSelectedChampion, setCurrentSelectedChampion] = useState({});

  const handleSelectChampion = (id) => {
    if (!toggleShow) setToggleShow(true);
    const currentChampion = data.filter((champ) => champ.id === id)[0];
    setCurrentSelectedChampion(currentChampion);

  };

  return (
    
    <div className="champions">
      {data.map((postData) => {
        return (
          <div  onClick={() => handleSelectChampion(postData.id) } >
            <div className="champion">
              <img className="champion__Image" src={postData.image}></img>
              <h4 className="champion__Name">{postData.name}</h4>
            
             
               
              {toggleShow && currentSelectedChampion.id === postData.id && (
                <>
                  <Skills currentChampion={currentSelectedChampion} />
                  <p onClick={() => setToggleShow(false)}>Close</p>
                </>
              )}
             </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Champions



Skills Component


import React from "react";
import "./Skills";


const Skills = ({ currentChampion }) => {
    return (
      <div className="spells">       
          <p className='name__Spell'> {currentChampion.textQ}</p>
          <img className='skill__Image' src={currentChampion.image1}></img>
          <h5 className='champ__Info'>{currentChampion.qInfo}</h5>    
          <p className='name__Spell' > {currentChampion.textW}</p>
          <img className='skill__Image' src={currentChampion.image2}></img>
          <h4 className='champ__Info'>{currentChampion.wInfo}</h4>
          <p className='name__Spell'> {currentChampion.textE}</p>
          <img className='skill__Image'  src={currentChampion.image3}></img>
          <h4 className='champ__Info'>{currentChampion.eInfo}</h4>
          <p className='name__Spell'> {currentChampion.textR}</p>
          <img className='skill__Image' src={currentChampion.image4}></img>
          <h4 className='champ__Info'>{currentChampion.RInfo}</h4>       
      </div>
    );
  };



  export default Skills


JSON
[
{    
"id":1,
 "name": "Aatrox",
"image": "/champions/Aatrox_0.jpg",
"textQ":"Q",
"qInfo": "The darlking Blade Aatrox slams his greatsword down, dealing physical damage. He can swing three times, each with a different area of effect",
"image1": "/spell/AatroxQ.png",          
"textW": "W",
 "wInfo": "Aatrox smashes the ground, dealing damage to the first enemy hit. Champions and large monsters have to leave the impact area quickly or they will be dragged to the center and take the damage again.",
 "image2" : "/spell/AatroxW.png",
 "textE" : "E",
 "eInfo" : " Passively, Aatrox heals when damaging enemy champions. On activation, he dashes in a direction.",
 "image3" :"/spell/AatroxE.png",
 "textR" : "R",
 "RInfo" : "Aatrox unleashes his demonic form, fearing nearby enemy minions and gaining attack damage, increased healing, and movement speed. If he gets a takedown, this effect is extended."    , 
 "image4" : "/spell/AatroxR.png"
},

    
{            
"id":2,
"name": "Ahri",
"image": "/champions/Ahri_0.jpg",
    "textQ":"Q",
    "image1": "/spell/AhriOrbofDeception.png",
    "qInfo": "Ahri sends out and pulls back her orb, dealing magic damage on the way out and true damage on the way back.",
    "image2": "/spell/AhriFoxFire.png",          
    "textW": "W",
     "wInfo": "Ahri gains a brief burst of movement speed and releases three fox-fires, that lock onto and attack nearby enemies",
     "image3": "/spell/AhriSeduce.png",
     "textE" : "E",
     "eInfo" : "Ahri blows a kiss that damages and charms an enemy it encounters, instantly stopping movement abilities and causing them to walk harmlessly towards her. The target temporarily takes increased damage from Ahri.",
     "image4": "/spell/AhriTumble.png",
     "textR" : "R",
     "RInfo" : "Ahri dashes forward and fires essence bolts, damaging nearby enemies. Spirit Rush can be cast up to three times before going on cooldown."   
},
    

Search Component

import React from 'react'

const Search=(props)=> {

 const [searchValue, setSearchValue]=React.useState('')
 const handleSearchInputChanges =(e) =>{
  setSearchValue (e.target.value)     
}  
 
return (
    <form className="search">
            <input 
            value ={searchValue} 
            onChange={handleSearchInputChanges}
            type='text'
           />       
    </form>      
    )
}

export default Search
```

Comment: "I want from it when I write the name of the object which is in the json file, that it only displays that one and hides the others" -- do you mean when you find the matching object from either json file? You might take a look at [react-select](https://react-select.com/home) -- it allows searching in options and also creating different groups of options.

Comment: @displacedTexan simpleSearch when I write the name which is located in json it only displays  the content of that  name/id

Answer (score 0):

One possible way would be to filter the array.

```js
<div className="champions">
  {data
    .filter((postData) => currentSelectedChampion.id === postData.id)
    .map((postData) => {
      return (
        <div onClick={() => handleSelectChampion(postData.id)}>
          <div className="champion">
            <img className="champion__Image" src={postData.image}></img>
            <h4 className="champion__Name">{postData.name}</h4>

            {toggleShow && 
                (<>
                  <Skills currentChampion={currentSelectedChampion} />
                  <p onClick={() => setToggleShow(false)}>Close</p>
                </>)}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    })}
</div>
```

If you want to show all and only the filtered version if selected, then set the filtered array to state and set the full array back once the search value is for example empty

Comment: I had the json.stringify still in it. Can you say what does not work?

Comment: It removes them all, now I cant see any content

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant with the text. You will then need to set the filtered array to state, map over the array in state. once there is no search value "reset" the array in state to show everything again.

Comment: No, you can ask which part is unclear, otherwise there is no learning effect

Comment: That is interesting

Comment: I have to map over the array in state in Search Component ?